# Expressjs Static files not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**My controller**

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var info = {title: 'Index'};
    res.render('index' , info);
};

exports.about = function(req, res){
    var info = {title: 'about'};
    res.render('about' , info);
};

exports.post = function(req, res){
    var info = {title: 'Post'};
    res.render('post' , info);
};
```

**My routes.**

```
var controller = require('../controllers/controller');
var router = require('express').Router();

router.route('/').get(controller.index)
router.route('/posts/:slug').get(controller.post)
router.route('/about').get(controller.about);

module.exports = router;
```

**Server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var router = require(__dirname + '/routes/router');

var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8090;

app.use('/', router);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(port);
```

**Problem**

When I got to `http://localhost:8090/` or `http://localhost:8090/about` my static files work.

But if I visit any of the posts for example `http://localhost:8090/posts/lorem-ipsum` I get `GET error` in browser console. ( tried to server file from path `http://localhost:8090/posts/css/style.css` )

Comment: Since you didn't specify mount point, your static files are served from the root `/`, and your requests are for relative path to each page, ie `http://localhost:8090/posts/`, change relative paths to root relative paths for your static files `/css/style.css` instead of `css/style.css`

Comment: I am a bit confused. If you are serving static file, they will not be rendered by the view engine and your route handler will not be called at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: @marzelin Do you want to post that as your answer? Since that solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to serve static files first and then your routes, just switch line like this :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/', router);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure(?) that positioning in this case doesn't matter since I've tried moving that code everywhere from beginning to ending of the file , and it still doesn't work.

Comment: For me that did the job... But I just see your routes maybe try to rename your assets because you have some conflict between your files and your routes. Under public if you have a folder posts it will be conflicting with your route /posts/:slug can you try css/posts instead ? To see if it's better

Comment: The order definitely matters, i read an article somewhere that all route handlers (include static file handler) are stored in the same global array and they are resolved by the order in the array.